# MKPolyline draws strange relics when zooming

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I draw MKPolyline on map. Sometimes when I zoom a couple of times, something like this is left on the map:

[image]

Is it something specific for iOS maps that I cannot improve?

Or maybe with my drawing method something is wrong?

**my MKPolyline class:**

```
class MulticolorPolylineSegment: MKPolyline {
var color: UIColor?

class func colorSegments(forLocations locations: [Location]) -> [MulticolorPolylineSegment] {
    var colorSegments = [MulticolorPolylineSegment]()


    let red   = (r: 254.0/255.0, g: 200.0 / 255.0, b: 20.0/255.0)

    // RGB for Yellow (middle)
    let yellow = (r: 254.0/255.0, g: 200.0 / 255.0, b: 20.0/255.0)

    // RGB for Green (fastest)
    let green  = (r: 254.0/255.0, g: 200.0 / 255.0, b: 20.0/255.0)
    let (speeds, minSpeed, maxSpeed) = allSpeeds(forLocations: locations)

    // now knowing the slowest+fastest, we can get mean too
    let meanSpeed = (minSpeed + maxSpeed)/2

    for i in 1..<locations.count {
        let l1 = locations[i-1]
        let l2 = locations[i]
        print("dsd")
        var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

        coords.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: l1.latitude, longitude: l1.longitude))
        coords.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: l2.latitude, longitude: l2.longitude))

        let speed = speeds[i-1]
        var color = UIColor.black

        if speed < minSpeed { // Between Red & Yellow
            let ratio = (speed - minSpeed) / (meanSpeed - minSpeed)
            let r = CGFloat(red.r + ratio * (yellow.r - red.r))
            let g = CGFloat(red.g + ratio * (yellow.g - red.g))
            let b = CGFloat(red.r + ratio * (yellow.r - red.r))
            color = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
        }
        else { // Between Yellow & Green
            let ratio = (speed - meanSpeed) / (maxSpeed - meanSpeed)
            let r = CGFloat(yellow.r + ratio * (green.r - yellow.r))
            let g = CGFloat(yellow.g + ratio * (green.g - yellow.g))
            let b = CGFloat(yellow.b + ratio * (green.b - yellow.b))
            color = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
        }

        let segment = MulticolorPolylineSegment(coordinates: &coords, count: coords.count)
        segment.color = color
        colorSegments.append(segment)
    }

    return colorSegments
}

fileprivate class func allSpeeds(forLocations locations: [Location]) -> (speeds: [Double], minSpeed: Double, maxSpeed: Double) {
    // Make Array of all speeds. Find slowest and fastest
    var speeds = [Double]()
    var minSpeed = DBL_MAX
    var maxSpeed = 0.0

    for i in 1..<locations.count {
        let l1 = locations[i-1]
        let l2 = locations[i]

        let cl1 = CLLocation(latitude: l1.latitude, longitude: l1.longitude)
        let cl2 = CLLocation(latitude: l2.latitude, longitude: l2.longitude)

        let distance = cl2.distance(from: cl1)
        let time = l2.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(l1.timestamp as Date)
        let speed = distance/time

        minSpeed = min(minSpeed, speed)
        maxSpeed = max(maxSpeed, speed)

        speeds.append(speed)
    }

    return (speeds, minSpeed, maxSpeed)
}

}
```

**View Controller methods implementation**

```
@objc(mapView:rendererForOverlay:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {


    let polyline = overlay as! MulticolorPolylineSegment
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
    renderer.strokeColor = polyline.color
    renderer.lineWidth = 10
    return renderer
}

func polyline() -> MKPolyline {
    var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    let locations = self.locations
    for location in locations {
        coords.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude))
        print("dodalo")
    }

    return MKPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: run.locations.count)
}
```

Comment: Any update about this issue @DCDC?

Comment: @DaSilva Unfortunately not, maybe some custom drawing would solve the issue, but haven't tested it. I keep looking forward for solution

Comment: Thanks for you answer @DCDC. Now we are two looking for the same.

Comment: Count me in. I got the same issue: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/gk/vco3rg2sqnc9.png